# Fixing wall mounted towel rail to plasterboard wall

Tags: drywall, drywall-anchor

I have a narrow ensuite and so am looking for a space saving towel rail solution, such as [this](https://www.argos.co.uk/product/6063546).

Unfortunately, I believe the studs in my wall or located such that one is within my shower and the next is in the middle of the gap between the shower and sink where I would like to affix the towel rail.

Are there any plasterboard fixings that would be suitable to achieve this in order to hold to bath sheets and possibly a hand towel? I believe the two strongest are [drill in](https://www.diy.com/departments/diall-self-drilling-nylon-plugs-l-32mm-dia-14mm-pack-of-6/1584903_BQ.prd) and [toggle](https://www.diy.com/departments/diall-steel-spring-toggle-pack-of-2/1511941_BQ.prd)?

Am I asking too much of my wall?

Thanks

Edit: Or are [these](https://www.plasplugs.co.uk/hollow-wall-fixings/heavy-duty-plasterboard-fixings/10-heavy-duty-plasterboard-fixings/) better? What is everyone's thoughts on [GripIt](http://www.gripitfixings.co.uk) Anchors?

Answer (score 1):

Towel bars are routinely secured to the wall with drywall anchors, as even wet towels are well within the holding capacity of the anchors. Product recommendations are off-topic here, but any of the types of products you linked would work.

Note that towel bars are not grab bars, and if they are used as such the drywall anchors will fail. Grab bars must be installed into studs.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was mostly concerned as this would be mutiple towels protruding out from the wall instead of vertically like a towel radiator. Could you point me in the direction of somewhere more appropriate to ask about the different fixings (or a guide) as most I have seen do not appear detailed or provide load capacities. I didn't realise this would be off-topic. Some guides even seem somewhat contradictory or too general.

Answer (score -1):

Use toggles if no studs are near by, dont bother with the plastic junk.The metal toggles are the ones i use